# Access MySQL field's Comments with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

When you are creating a field in a MySQL table, there's a 'Comments' box to fill out. How can I access the data in that 'Comments' box with PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Poke around `information_schema`.

```
SELECT table_comment
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'myschema' AND table_name = 'mytable'
```

Comment: Hey please tell me what is `comments`, `myschema` and `mytable` ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948806/how-to-get-mysql-table-column-comment-text-in-php

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'comments' in 'field list'. Did you mean `table_comment`?

Comment: @chatfun `comments` should be `column_comment`. `myschema` is the database name and `mytable` the table name.
@Pang That's because the right table should be `information_schema.columns`.
I edited the query because is the one accepted as the best answer.

Comment: jayarjo's answer is helpful, *but this one does address penetra's question directly*. To make it work, Leopoldo's notes are necessary.

Answer (score 63):

Use:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM tbl_name
```

Notice keyword **FULL**, this is what makes MySQL to include privileges and comments info  into the response.

Comment: You saved me a million years :)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM 
    information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'venue'
```

Great to use for table column headings or more readable/secure version of real column names.  Ex., The column for Venue ID is actually vid_xt

Sample Result from actual query above:

```
COLUMN_COMMENT
Venue ID
Venue Active
Venue Name
Location Name
Address
Accommodations
Description
```

Answer (score 6):

Ah, wow. So that's what information_schema database is for. Thank you @Adam Backstrom! Then I believe below should give me the **field**'s comments.

```
SELECT COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydatabase' AND TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'mycolumn'
```

Thank you for pointing me to the right direction. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I discovered that the following query does the trick for me:

```sql
select column_comment from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = "YOUR_SCHEMA" 
and table_name = "YOUR_TABLE";
```