# Mysql: accessing field's comments for multiple-table outputs

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Mysql queries can in principle produce results with fields from different tables. These fields have each different comments and I would like to retrieve those in the most DIRECT and STRAIGHTFORWARD way.
One would naively imagine based on the phylosophy of OO programing that the mysqli->fetch_field() will give direct access to that, but it simply doesnt. So my question is two-fold:

A- What is the most straighforward way to get the field's comments from the result of the query that contains multiple-table fields.

B- Shouldn't that feature be incorporated directly into php's fetch_field ??

Thanks for the help

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097973/access-mysql-fields-comments-with-php

Comment: Obviously I've seen most of these answers and they are not in any way satisfying in which they are not direct or straightforward. This question refers to a result with fields from different tables and retrieving the comments the suggested way is really cumbersome and not OO at all. Any lean php code that can be used to retrieve comments for ANY custom query's result is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: That question shows the two possible ways:  SHOW FULL COLUMNS or accessing the information schema table.  How you access the SQL query is your choice, it can be OO if you want to do a fetch using those SQL queries...I'm not sure what else you are asking.  Column comments aren't included in a normal SELECT.