# How to get MySQL table column comment text in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting [Access MySQL field's Comments with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097973/access-mysql-fields-comments-with-php) but this link is not working for me Please check my question.

i have a table name `config` there is 3 column `id`,`notification` and `newsletter`.

in `notification` column i have added comment `0=No, 1=Yes` and `newsletter` column contains `0=No, 1=Weekly, 2=Monthly` I want to get both comment in PHP code.

How to getting comment in below table?

```
CREATE TABLE `raddyx_learnphp`.`config` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`notification` TINYINT NOT NULL COMMENT '0=No, 1=Yes',
`newsletter` TINYINT NOT NULL COMMENT '0=No, 1=Weekly, 2=Monthly'
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `raddyx_learnphp`.`config` (`id`, `notification`, `newsletter`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '0');
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db('raddyx_learnphp',$con);

$query = 'select * from config WHERE id=1';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 0;
$getResult=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
while ($i < mysql_num_fields($result)){
    $fld = mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    $myarray=$fld->name;
    $i = $i + 1;

    echo $myarray.' = '.$getResult[$myarray];
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

```
id = 1
notification = 1
newsletter = 0
```

Above code i am getting `column name` and `value` i want to also show `comment`. How to show the field comments?

Comment: John Conde Please give me the duplicate link

Comment: Sorry John Conde Your duplicate link is different.

Comment: John This is not duplicate question. Please allow to give answer. I want to `column name`, `value` and `column comment` not only `column comment`

Comment: You just use 2 separate queries for that, or use some union query if you want to. Information about table structure (and comments are stored there) is stored separately in different database 'information_schema'. This is why your question was marked as duplicate, because there is already a question on how to get the info you want. You just need to write your SQL query the way you want to.